# Django is not generating database tables from models

Tags: python, django

I have my project with some apps.
like:

```
MainProject
|---- client
      |----models.py
```

I'm trying to generate the models that I have in my `client/models.py`

The models are like:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    lastname = models.TextField()
    picture = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    registeredlanguage = models.TextField()
    id_language = models.ForeignKey('Language', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_language')
    email = models.TextField()
    phone = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_gender = models.ForeignKey('Gender', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_gender')
    birthdate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    facebookid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        db_table = 'client'
```

The models were generated in a previous project (some years ago), and now when I try to generate the tables again, any table is generated.
How I can apply the models from my project into my database?

```
# python manage.py showmigrations

account
 (no migrations)
admin
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
api
 (no migrations)
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [ ] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
catalog
 (no migrations)
client
 [ ] 0001_initial
```

Also

```
# python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
# python manage.py makemigrations client
No changes detected in app 'client'
```

Comment: By saying that *when I try to generate the tables again*, do you mean in the same database?

Comment: The database is new, I just created it with `Create database db` but has no any table yet

Comment: And I assume that in your `settings.py` file the [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) settings points to the new db, right?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I executed `manage.py migrate` and I'm getting the error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists`

Comment: What version of django are you running? and which version of python?

Comment: `# python --version
Python 3.4.5` and ` # django-admin --version
1.10.4` @BillF

Comment: did you try `python manage.py makemigrations` before `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I am not sure will this work for you but crude solution is delete all migrations and re- run 
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`
`python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: I did it, I deleted all the migrations and now gives  `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" already exists`

Comment: deleting Django_session data helps you ?

Comment: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_session"."expire_...` @Roshan